# How to add all vector elements using divide and conquer and iterators?

Tags: c++, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I needed to write a function that sums up all elements of a vector. Specifications are that it has to be done by recursion and the only parameters input would be iterators. The function should:Divide the vector in half, recurse on the left hand side, recurse on the right hand side, return the sum of both sides. I wrote the code below but I am getting an incorrect answer.

```
int sumVectorRecurse(vector<int>::iterator left, vector<int>::iterator right)
{
    if (left != right){
        int midPosition = (right - left)/2;
        vector<int>::iterator mid = left + midPosition;
        return (sumVectorRecurse(left, mid) + sumVectorRecurse(mid+1, right));
    }
    else return *left;
}

int main(){

    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    cout << endl << "THIS IS QUESTION 4:"<< endl;
    cout << sumVectorRecurse(v.begin(), v.end());

}
```

Update: the output is okay for a vector till `{1,2,3,4}` but once I add 5 to it making it `{1,2,3,4,5}` the output is "32782"

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged this?

Comment: Update: the output is okay for a vector till {1,2,3,4} but once I add 5 to it making it {1,2,3,4,5} the output is "32782"
The output is wrong, there are no error though

Comment: This is not a complete program.  It sounds a lot like there's a mistake in the code that you decided not to show us.

Comment: Think about what passing `end` means.  You can't dereference it.

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing the `end` iterator, which is undefined behavior.

C++ ranges are, by convention, specified by a pair of iterators where the left iterator points to the first item, and the right iterator points **one past the last item**.  This allows a range to be empty, by having `begin == end`.

Your base cases should be:

```
if (left == right) return 0;
if (left + 1 == right) return *left;
```

Then, pass `mid` to both halves of the recursion, because it will be included in the second half (where it is the left iterator), and excluded in the first half (where it is the end iterator).

```
int sumVectorRecurse(vector<int>::iterator left, vector<int>::iterator right)
{
    if (left == right) return 0;
    if (left + 1 == right) return *left;
    int midPosition = (right - left)/2;
    vector<int>::iterator mid = left + midPosition;
    return sumVectorRecurse(left, mid) + sumVectorRecurse(mid, right);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`v.end()` is **not** a dereferencable iterator.  It represents "one past the end".

This will work.

```
sumVectorRecurse( v.begin(), v.end() - 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew! I didn't even think that part would matter and that's why I had't put it up! First post ever here! This was really helpful thanks! :)